# "configure:2981: error: C compiler cannot create executables"

Tags: autotools, icc, flexlm

I am trying to install gtkdialog , but when I run the ./configure I get the error mentioned in the the subject.

Is there a work around it?

Here is my Log file:

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by gtkdialog configure 0.8.3, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.63.  Invocation command line was

  $ ./configure --enable-maintainer-mode

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = adira0150
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 2.6.32-431.23.3.el6.x86_64
uname -s = Linux
uname -v = #1 SMP Thu Jul 31 17:20:51 UTC 2014

/usr/bin/uname -p = unknown
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = x86_64
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /d/home/share/scripts
PATH: /d/home/share/bin
PATH: /d/sw/prod/scripts
PATH: /d/sw/prod/bin
PATH: /d/sw/itdt_se/7.1.0.065/
PATH: /d/sw/tcopy/latest/bin
PATH: /d/sw/slurm/latest/bin
PATH: /d/sw/slurm/scripts
PATH: /d/sw/firefox/stable
PATH: /d/sw/dusegd/latest
PATH: /d/sw/Acrobat/9.5.5-1/Adobe/Reader9/bin
PATH: /d/sw/Claritas/V6-2.1.11948/bin
PATH: /d/sw/openmpi/1.6.5/bin
PATH: /d/sw/scilab/5.5.2/bin
PATH: /d/sw/BHPSU/unknown/bin
PATH: /d/sw/BHPSU/7.0/dev/bin/Linux
PATH: /d/sw/intel/2013.4.183/bin
PATH: /d/sw/intel/2013.4.183/vtune_amplifier_xe_2013/bin64
PATH: /d/sw/intel/2013.4.183/cilkutil/bin
PATH: /d/sw/intel/2013.4.183/vtune_amplifier_xe_2013/target
PATH: /d/sw/delivery/100531/NativeCodes/bin/Linux-x86_64-unknown
PATH: /d/sw/delivery/100531/scripts
PATH: /d/sw/cwp.su/38/bin
PATH: /d/sw/Wavelet/latest
PATH: /d/sw/dugio/latest
PATH: /d/sw/dugs/latest
PATH: /d/sw/fftw/3.2.2/bin
PATH: /d/sw/autoreport/20140410
PATH: /d/sw/qhull/2003.1/
PATH: /d/sw/Well/1.78-312120
PATH: /d/sw/Rock/latest
PATH: /d/sw/Insight/latest/scripts
PATH: /d/sw/Insight/latest
PATH: /d/sw/Insight/latest/Nemo/bin
PATH: /d/sw/java64/jdk1.7.0_65/bin
PATH: /usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/local/sbin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /sbin
PATH: /d/sw/bin
PATH: .
PATH: /d/sw/scripts
PATH: /d/sw/deli/4.0/bin


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:1922: checking for a BSD-compatible install
configure:1990: result: /usr/bin/install -c
configure:2001: checking whether build environment is sane
configure:2061: result: yes
configure:2202: checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p
configure:2241: result: /bin/mkdir -p
configure:2254: checking for gawk
configure:2270: found /usr/bin/gawk
configure:2281: result: gawk
configure:2292: checking whether make sets $(MAKE)
configure:2314: result: yes
configure:2399: checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles
configure:2408: result: yes
configure:2425: checking for svnversion
configure:2443: found /usr/bin/svnversion
configure:2455: result: /usr/bin/svnversion
configure:2494: checking for style of include used by make
configure:2522: result: GNU
configure:2592: checking for gcc
configure:2619: result: icc
configure:2851: checking for C compiler version
configure:2859: icc --version >&5

Error: A license for CCompL is not available now (-15,570,115).

A connection to the license server could not be made.  You should
make sure that your license daemon process is running: both an
lmgrd process and an INTEL process should be running
if your license limits you to a specified number of licenses in use
at a time.  Also, check to see if the wrong port@host or the wrong
license file is being used, or if the port or hostname in the license
file has changed.

License file(s) used were (in this order):
    1.  Trusted Storage
**  2.  /d/sw/intel/flexlm/server.lic
**  3.  /d/sw/intel/2013.4.183/composer_xe_2013.4.183/Licenses
**  4.  /d/home/adira0150/intel/licenses
**  5.  /opt/intel/licenses
**  6.  /Users/Shared/Library/Application Support/Intel/Licenses
**  7.  /d/sw/intel/2013.4.183/composer_xe_2013.4.183/bin/intel64/*.lic

Please visit http://software.intel.com/sites/support/ if you require technical assistance.

icc: error #10052: could not checkout FLEXlm license
configure:2863: $? = 1
configure:2870: icc -v >&5

Error: A license for CCompL is not available now (-15,570,115).

A connection to the license server could not be made.  You should
make sure that your license daemon process is running: both an
lmgrd process and an INTEL process should be running
if your license limits you to a specified number of licenses in use
at a time.  Also, check to see if the wrong port@host or the wrong
license file is being used, or if the port or hostname in the license
file has changed.

License file(s) used were (in this order):
    1.  Trusted Storage
**  2.  /d/sw/intel/flexlm/server.lic
**  3.  /d/sw/intel/2013.4.183/composer_xe_2013.4.183/Licenses
**  4.  /d/home/adira0150/intel/licenses
**  5.  /opt/intel/licenses
**  6.  /Users/Shared/Library/Application Support/Intel/Licenses
**  7.  /d/sw/intel/2013.4.183/composer_xe_2013.4.183/bin/intel64/*.lic

Please visit http://software.intel.com/sites/support/ if you require technical assistance.

icc: error #10052: could not checkout FLEXlm license
configure:2874: $? = 1
configure:2881: icc -V >&5

Error: A license for CCompL is not available now (-15,570,115).

A connection to the license server could not be made.  You should
make sure that your license daemon process is running: both an
lmgrd process and an INTEL process should be running
if your license limits you to a specified number of licenses in use
at a time.  Also, check to see if the wrong port@host or the wrong
license file is being used, or if the port or hostname in the license
file has changed.

License file(s) used were (in this order):
    1.  Trusted Storage
**  2.  /d/sw/intel/flexlm/server.lic
**  3.  /d/sw/intel/2013.4.183/composer_xe_2013.4.183/Licenses
**  4.  /d/home/adira0150/intel/licenses
**  5.  /opt/intel/licenses
**  6.  /Users/Shared/Library/Application Support/Intel/Licenses
**  7.  /d/sw/intel/2013.4.183/composer_xe_2013.4.183/bin/intel64/*.lic

Please visit http://software.intel.com/sites/support/ if you require technical assistance.

icc: error #10052: could not checkout FLEXlm license
configure:2885: $? = 1
configure:2908: checking for C compiler default output file name
configure:2930: icc    conftest.c  >&5

Error: A license for CCompL is not available now (-15,570,115).

A connection to the license server could not be made.  You should
make sure that your license daemon process is running: both an
lmgrd process and an INTEL process should be running
if your license limits you to a specified number of licenses in use
at a time.  Also, check to see if the wrong port@host or the wrong
license file is being used, or if the port or hostname in the license
file has changed.

License file(s) used were (in this order):
    1.  Trusted Storage
**  2.  /d/sw/intel/flexlm/server.lic
**  3.  /d/sw/intel/2013.4.183/composer_xe_2013.4.183/Licenses
**  4.  /d/home/adira0150/intel/licenses
**  5.  /opt/intel/licenses
**  6.  /Users/Shared/Library/Application Support/Intel/Licenses
**  7.  /d/sw/intel/2013.4.183/composer_xe_2013.4.183/bin/intel64/*.lic

Please visit http://software.intel.com/sites/support/ if you require technical assistance.

icc: error #10052: could not checkout FLEXlm license
configure:2934: $? = 1
configure:2972: result: 
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h.  */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "gtkdialog"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "gtkdialog"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "0.8.3"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "gtkdialog 0.8.3"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "thunorsif@hotmail.com"
| #define PACKAGE "gtkdialog"
| #define VERSION "0.8.3"
| #define BUILD_DETAILS "release"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:2978: error: in `/d/home/share/scripts/Abhi/gtkdialog-0.8.3':
configure:2981: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details.

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_env_CC_set=set
ac_cv_env_CC_value=icc
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
ac_cv_env_GLADE_LIB_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_GLADE_LIB_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_GLADE_LIB_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_GLADE_LIB_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_GTHREAD_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_GTHREAD_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_GTHREAD_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_GTHREAD_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_GTK_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_GTK_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_GTK_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_GTK_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_set=
ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_value=
ac_cv_env_VTE_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_VTE_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_VTE_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_VTE_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_YACC_set=
ac_cv_env_YACC_value=
ac_cv_env_YFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_YFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_path_install='/usr/bin/install -c'
ac_cv_path_mkdir=/bin/mkdir
ac_cv_path_svnv=/usr/bin/svnversion
ac_cv_prog_AWK=gawk
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_CC=icc
ac_cv_prog_make_make_set=yes

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

ACLOCAL='${SHELL} /d/home/share/scripts/Abhi/gtkdialog-0.8.3/missing --run aclocal-1.11'
AMDEPBACKSLASH='\'
AMDEP_FALSE='#'
AMDEP_TRUE=''
AMTAR='${SHELL} /d/home/share/scripts/Abhi/gtkdialog-0.8.3/missing --run tar'
AUTOCONF='${SHELL} /d/home/share/scripts/Abhi/gtkdialog-0.8.3/missing --run autoconf'
AUTOHEADER='${SHELL} /d/home/share/scripts/Abhi/gtkdialog-0.8.3/missing --run autoheader'
AUTOMAKE='${SHELL} /d/home/share/scripts/Abhi/gtkdialog-0.8.3/missing --run automake-1.11'
AWK='gawk'
CC='icc'
CCDEPMODE=''
CFLAGS=''
CPP=''
CPPFLAGS=''
CYGPATH_W='echo'
DEFS=''
DEPDIR='.deps'
ECHO_C=''
ECHO_N='-n'
ECHO_T=''
EGREP=''
EXEEXT=''
GLADE_LIB_CFLAGS=''
GLADE_LIB_LIBS=''
GREP=''
GTHREAD_CFLAGS=''
GTHREAD_LIBS=''
GTK_CFLAGS=''
GTK_LIBS=''
HAVE_GLADE_LIB=''
HAVE_VTE=''
INSTALL_DATA='${INSTALL} -m 644'
INSTALL_PROGRAM='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_SCRIPT='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_STRIP_PROGRAM='$(install_sh) -c -s'
LDFLAGS=''
LEX=''
LEXLIB=''
LEX_OUTPUT_ROOT=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBS=''
LTLIBOBJS=''
MAINT=''
MAINTAINER_MODE_FALSE='#'
MAINTAINER_MODE_TRUE=''
MAKEINFO='${SHELL} /d/home/share/scripts/Abhi/gtkdialog-0.8.3/missing --run makeinfo'
MKDIR_P='/bin/mkdir -p'
OBJEXT=''
PACKAGE='gtkdialog'
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT='thunorsif@hotmail.com'
PACKAGE_NAME='gtkdialog'
PACKAGE_STRING='gtkdialog 0.8.3'
PACKAGE_TARNAME='gtkdialog'
PACKAGE_VERSION='0.8.3'
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
PKG_CONFIG=''
SET_MAKE=''
SHELL='/bin/sh'
STRIP=''
VERSION='0.8.3'
VTE_CFLAGS=''
VTE_LIBS=''
YACC=''
YFLAGS=''
ac_ct_CC='icc'
am__EXEEXT_FALSE=''
am__EXEEXT_TRUE=''
am__fastdepCC_FALSE=''
am__fastdepCC_TRUE=''
am__include='include'
am__isrc=''
am__leading_dot='.'
am__quote=''
am__tar='${AMTAR} chof - "$$tardir"'
am__untar='${AMTAR} xf -'
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build_alias=''
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE_TARNAME}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec_prefix='NONE'
host_alias=''
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
install_sh='${SHELL} /d/home/share/scripts/Abhi/gtkdialog-0.8.3/install-sh'
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
mkdir_p='/bin/mkdir -p'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
prefix='NONE'
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
psdir='${docdir}'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
svnv='/usr/bin/svnversion'
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target_alias=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

#define PACKAGE_NAME "gtkdialog"
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME "gtkdialog"
#define PACKAGE_VERSION "0.8.3"
#define PACKAGE_STRING "gtkdialog 0.8.3"
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "thunorsif@hotmail.com"
#define PACKAGE "gtkdialog"
#define VERSION "0.8.3"
#define BUILD_DETAILS "release"

configure: exit 77
```

I am getting the same problem while building any package using the configure file .

Comment: Do you know which compiler you want to use? Because the error indicates that you did not properly install the Intel compilers yet are trying to use them.

Comment: Continuing on andlabs answer : if you are trying to use icc then all of your current tags are pretty useless (because it's not a gtk related issue at all) . Using `icc` and `flexlm` might get this in front of some specialists.

Comment: I actually don't agree with changing the tags to those just yet; I would first like to know if the OP is intentionally trying to use icc or not. I don't know what more appropriate tags would be: if the OP is trying to use icc, then yes, the icc tags are needed; if not, the question devolves into understanding that there are multiple compilers available on any given OS and the decision of which to use is important.

Comment: It is surprising that `configure` finds `icc` when it's actually looking for `gcc`.  This suggests that somebody has set up the compilation machine somewhat strangely.  If that somebody was not you, then ask them what you need to do to successfully run the (icc) compiler.